# Puppet lookup fails with expects a Stdlib::Port = Integer[0, 65535] value, got String

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I have a parameter of type Stdlib::Port which I would like to set via the lookup function in my yaml-file.

manifest:

```
class module1(
  Integer $logging_filesize,
  Optional[Stdlib::Port] $server_port,
) {
...
}
```

yaml:

```
---
public:
  port_1: 8080
  port_2: 443

module1::server_port: "%lookup('public.port_1')"
```

But I get the following error:

Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Class[module1]: parameter 'server_port' expects a Stdlib::Port = Integer[0, 65535] value, got String (line: 1, column: 35) on node xxxx

unfortunately a convert_to of the parameter did not work

```
lookup_options:
  module1::server_port:
    convert_to: "Integer"
```

Comment: The value is stored in the data as an Integer, but then cast to String during interpolation. You should probably pass the parameter directly instead of casting to a string in an intermediate step containing no other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same YAML document, you could [alias keys](https://YAML.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#aliases_and_anchors).
In Puppet there is also an [`alias` function](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/hiera_merging#hiera_interpolation-interpolation-token).

```
---
public:
  port_1: 8080
  port_2: 443

module1::server_port: "%alias('public.port_1')"
```

Note, although the `"` delimiter usually suggest a *string* value, the `alias` interpolation function is special:
If there is *only* an `%alias{…}` within a value, the data type of the aliased value is preserved.